# SuityeCRM - jQuery Code not working On Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, sugarcrm, suitecrm

```
 $("#subpanel_title_documents").click(function(){
    alert("clicked");

        alert("loaded");
        $("#documents_cases_create_button").click(function(){
            alert("clicked");
             setTimeout(function(){console.log("undefined");},1000);
             alert("test");
             setTimeout(function(){
                if($("#account_id").attr("data-id-value") != ""){
                    alert("account");
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        var idAccount = $("#account_id").attr("data-id-value");
                        var nAccount = $("#account_id").text();

                        alert(idAccount);
                        alert(nAccount);

                         $("#account_id_c").val(idAccount);
                         $("#accounts_c").val(nAccount);
                    },500);


                }else{
                    $("#subpanel_title_contacts").click();
                        alert("subpanel open");
                        setTimeout(function(){
                                    var idcontact = $("*[data-module='Contacts']").data("record-id");
                                    var nomecontact = $("*[data-module='Contacts']").data("module-name");

                                    alert(idcontact);
                                    alert(nomecontact);

                                    $("#contact_id_c").val(idcontact);
                                    $("#contacts_c").val(nomecontact);
                                    $("#Documents_subpanel_full_form_button").click();
                        },1500);
                };
            },1000);
        });

});
```

I'm trying to populate some fields on SuiteCRM after some actions. 
This code works well on Mozilla Firefox but not on Google Chrome. After second Alert ( alert("loaded") ) stops working on Chrome.
Can anyone understand what is the issue?

Comment: The whole of the code you've posted is inside the first `.click()` function - including the later `click()` functions - is that what you intended?

Comment: @peeebeee yes, is what I intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include some more details, like in which module/detail view/edit vew/popup are you trying this.

For instance in the account module this ID `documents_cases_create_button`  doesn't exist.

Furthermore, I haven't found evidence that this `documents_cases_create_button` exists in the SuiteCRM official repo.

If you are doing something custom, please specify.

also, if you are loading content using AJAX, and that AJAX is executed at the same time that `$("#subpanel_title_documents").click(function(){` is Clicked, then the DOM object  `documents_cases_create_button`  might not be there quite yet.

If you don't know, the set a timeout before setting this listener

```
 $("#subpanel_title_documents").click(function(){
    console.log("Documents Clicked")
    setTimeout(function(){
       console.log("Just waited 3 secs for dom to finish loading AJAX content")
       $("#documents_cases_create_button").click(function(){
           console.log("I finally got the event I wanted");
       })
    },3000);
  })
```

If that was the issue, then your option will be to set some kind of Observer. (thats what I do for AJAX loaded content when there are no native callbacks).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I'm trying to do this on Cases module (Detail View) to fill Documents Quick Form.

`documents_cases_create_button` ID exists only if Documents Quick Form is activated. It's the button for QuickCreate.

I've tried to set a timeout before setting `$("#subpanel_title_documents").click(function(){`but it makes no difference. Before `$("#subpanel_title_documents").click(function(){`, every instructions works. After that, none of them works.

I'll try to set a Observer to know if it works on Chrome.

Comment: Just checked and my answer was correct, the create button ain't rendered until some X time after the first click, thats why you cannot attach an event to a non-existent node. I updated the example to show you how to detect such an issue.

Comment: Yes,you was right. Now it works well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: nice, would you please mark the answer as correct :)